# got a vim mapping to show python code errors. Now I need to show it only if there are errors

Tags: python, vim

have these in my vimrc:

```
set makeprg=python\ %

map <F5> :w<CR> :silent make <bar> copen<CR> 
imap <F5> <Esc>:w<CR> :silent make <bar> copen<CR>i
```

it works, but I would like it better if the quickfix window doesnt open if there are no errors. I found some info (and a quite similar question here in SO about a klang compiler) but i dont understand this stuff very well, can anyone help? ty.

edit: the quickfix window is empty if there are no errors, so i guess it is a matter of checking its contents, but this is very far from my limited vim-fu

Answer (score 1):

It might be far easier to use a dedicated plugin like [vim-flake8](https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8). It can be configured to check Python syntax on each buffer save, so you do not need to misuse the 'make' program setting:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.py call Flake8()
```

Errors open in the quick fix window, and the quick fix window does not open if there are no errors, as you request.

**EDIT**: ... but if you insist on using only vimrc-based tricks (which is more portable, you are right), then you have to remove the `copen` part of your commands, because that is what is forcing to open the quick fix window on every run:

```
map <F5> :w<CR> :silent make <bar><CR> 
imap <F5> <Esc>:w<CR> :silent make <bar><CR>i
```

Comment: Yep, but i'm wary of plugins. I don't know if i'm wrong, but i feel I'd be better off if my vim skills depend only in a portable vimrc file instead of depending on a lot of plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing your python code not linting it. A quick google shows [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) and [Python - check syntax and run script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Python_-_check_syntax_and_run_script). There is also [synstastic.vim](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) if you want a heavier handed approach. I have created a [simple python compiler plugin](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/33dfe9e4203ceab2c518) if you wish to use it.

To answer your question you can use `:cwindow` instead of `:copen` to only open the quickfix list windown when errors are present.

Optionally: A common approach is to use an `:autocmd` to execute `:cwindow`/`:copen` after `:make`. e.g `autocmd QuickFixCmdPost * cwindow`

Some thoughts on your mappings:

- It is usually best to supply a mapping so `map` would become `nmap`
- General rule of thumb use `*noremap` unless using `<Plug>` mappings
- There is a space in the mapping that will move the cursor
- Needlesss `<bar>`
- The "Vim Way" typically avoids executing commands from insert mode

Cleaned up version of you mapping:

```
nnoremap <f5> :w<cr>:silent make<cr>:cwindow<cr>
```

For more help see:

```
:h :make
:h 'makeprg'
:h :compiler
:h :cwindow
:h :compiler
:h write-compiler-plugin
```

Comment: ty, but don't know why this doesnt seem to work for me, I just get a 'cwindow' echoed in the command line.

Comment: If you don't have any errors then all you will see is `:cwindow` because that is the last executed command. Maybe you would like a nicer message. You can add `:cc` to print out the top message. Usually a "No syntax errors dected" kind of message in most linters. `nnoremap <f5> :w<cr>:silent make<cr>:cwindow<cr>:cc<cr>`

Comment: no, i mean i dont see the error reports even if there are some gross ones. The script doesnt work, it just fails silently.

Comment: Which script? What is `:set makeprg?` give you? If you open the quickfix window via `:copen` do any errors show up? Remember errors in the quickfix list will have both a filename and line number at the beginning.

Comment: yes, if I type copen or restore the previous settings, I get the errors of the python script. But nothing appears if I paste your line instead of the copen version...

Comment: When you open the quickfix list via `:copen` does line start with `||` ? If so that means that line is not read as an error. You will need to adjust your `'errorformat'` so errors can be parsed.